# SQL Select Query Combining two queries if/else, null, empty input

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

For example I have a table

```
State | Zip | CategoryID | ProductID
FL    |12345|     2      |  3
GA    |98765|     1      |  5
GA    |98765|     1      |  4
```

My goal is to come up with a query that matches the state, zip, categoryID, and productID. However, my input for category 2 ProductID could be null or an empty string from the user cause there isn't always a productID associated with the input. If categoryID == 2, it doesn't really care about the specific productID. But if categoryID == 1, it cares about the productID. Is there an if/else I could do like if it's category 1 is it equal to the input or null or empty string and category 2 check the product id? Or is there a way I can make both of these queries into one?

If category 2, the input for productID could be 3, but could also be null or an empty string. So, if it is null, empty string, or 3. I need it to return.

```
FL    |12345|     2      |  3

select * from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
and l.zip = :zip
and l.category = :category
```

If category 1, the input for productID will always be there. So if we are querying for productID 4, it should return.

```
GA    |98765|     1      |  4

select * from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
and l.zip = :zip
and l.categoryID = :category
and l.productID = :productID
```

Comment: Which is it - sql server or oracle? It cant be both - please update your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select l.*
from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state and
      l.zip = :zip and
      l.categoryID = :category and
      (:category <> 2 or l.productID = :productID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear what conditions you are looking for, but this version assumes your that if your categoryid=2 then we not only get rows that match the :productID, but also we will match any row where either the parameter is null or the table contains a null.

BTW you mention null or empty string - I am assuming that they are integers in the table and the parameter, which means they will never be an empty string. If this isnt true then change the tests for `is null` to `isnull(l.productID,'')='' or isnull(:productID,'')=''`

Your test for categoryid would also have to be `categoryID='2'`

```
select l.*
from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state and
  l.zip = :zip and
  l.categoryID = :category and
  (l.productID = :productID 
     or (:category = 2 and (l.productID is null or :productID is null))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM locationPurch l
WHERE 
    -- we look just at categoryId 2
    (:category = 2 AND 
     l.CategoryId = 2 AND -- filter only products from Category 2 
     (
              :productId IS NULL OR -- :productId is not specified as filter
              (ISNULL(l.ProductId,-99) = :productId) OR -- :productId is specified
              (:productId IS NOT NULL AND l.ProductId IS NULL) -- :productId is specified but user hasn't inputed data for productId in table
     ) AND -- productId resolving
     (:state IS NULL OR l.state = :state) AND 
     (:zip IS NULL OR l.zip = :zip)
    ) 
    OR
    -- only category 1 is observed
    (:category = 1 AND 
     l.CategoryId = 1 AND -- filter only products from Category1 
     l.ProductId = :productId AND -- only specified productId 
     (:state IS NULL OR l.state = :state) AND -- if state is entered then use that state as filter
     (:zip IS NULL OR l.zip = :zip) -- if ZIP is entered use that zip as filter
    )
```

Edit: Part 2

You can join queries using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` operators like this:

```
select * from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
and l.zip = :zip
and l.category = :category
and l.category = 1
UNION ALL
select * from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
and l.zip = :zip
and l.categoryID = :category
and l.productID = :productID
and l.category = 2
```

* This is just for showing how to use UNION, this script has to be further improved by using WHERE clauses I've used in previous query.

But there are some limitations to using UNION, read here about them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this query:

```
select *
from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
  and l.zip = :zip
  and l.categoryID = :category
  and (
    l.categoryID = 2 or l.productID = :productID
  )
```

If `categoryID` is `2`, it will not care about the `productID` because of the `or` operator. If `categoryID` is any other value (that includes `1`), it would check for the `productID` after the `or` operator.

For this to work, the operands are enclosed in parentheses *ANDed* to the rest of the *where* clause.

Answer (score 0):

just try this.

```
select * from locationPurch l
where l.state = :state
and l.zip = :zip
and l.categoryID = :category
and l.productID = case when :category = 1 then :productID else l.productID end
```

it will give you your expected output